# Сдвиг рваного массива вниз/вверх

Tags: c#

Турдность состоит в том, что сдвиг должен быть циклическим по строкам и создавать дополнительные(временные) массивы нельзя. По задаче требуеться, что бы сдвиг происходил вверх и вниз

```
    int shift = InputShift(array);
        for (int count = 0; count < shift; count++)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
            {
                int temp = array[array.Length - 1][i];
                int j = 0;
                for (j = array.Length - 1; j > 0; j--)
                {
                    array[j][i] = array[j - 1][i];
                }
                array[j][i] = temp;
            }
        }
```

Вот, что получаеться, но по факту, не то что требуеться.
Должно получатся так:

```
            //До:       После:
            //1234      54876
            //54876     23
            //23        1234
            //2456      2456
```

Comment: Не, не должно. Как, интересно, `1234` затесалось между `23` и `2456`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Просто по приколу, вот вариант вообще без использования переменных.

```
public static void Shift(ref int[] array, in int amount)
{
    if (amount == 0)
        return;
    if (amount > 0)
    {
        ShiftFront(ref array);
        Shift(ref array, amount - 1);
    }
    if (amount < 0)
    {
        ShiftBack(ref array);
        Shift(ref array, amount + 1);
    }
}
static void ShiftBack(ref int[] array)
{
    for (int i = array.Length - 1; i >= 1; i--)
        Swap(ref array[i], ref array[i - 1]);
}
static void ShiftFront(ref int[] array)
{
    for (int i = 0; i + 1 < array.Length; i++)
        Swap(ref array[i], ref array[i + 1]);
}
static void Swap(ref int v1, ref int v2)
{
    v1 += v2;
    v2 = v1 - v2;
    v1 -= v2;
}
```

Ну и вызывать:

```
var array = new[] { 0, 1, 2, 3 };
Shift(ref array, -1);
```

Comment: `вариант вообще без использования переменных` ... `int i = 0` ?

Comment: Ща пофикшу. Забыл мозг включить.

Comment: ну и вы сдвигаете одномерный массив, а в вопросе речь о сдвиге для двухмерного.

Comment: А, так вот что такое "рваный". Пхх, и как его двигать? Типа смещать все элементы в нужную сторону?

Comment: по идее, это массив массивов, то есть замените у себя в ответе целые числа на массивы и получите сдвиг рваного массива.

Answer (score 2):

Какое значение здесь имеет "рваность" массива, если Вы (в примере) двигаете строку как одно целое?

```
for (int i = 0; i < shift % array.GetLength(0); i++) {
  for (int j = 0; j < array.GetLength(0) - 1; j++) {
    var temp = array[j];
    array[j] = array[j + 1];
    array[j + 1] = temp;
  }
}
```

```js
function shiftArray(array, shift) {
  for (var i = 0; i < shift % array.length; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < array.length - 1; j++) {
      var temp = array[j];
      array[j] = array[j + 1];
      array[j + 1] = temp;
    }
  }
}

var array = [1234, 54876, 23, 2456];
shiftArray(array, 2);
console.log(JSON.stringify(array));
```

Answer (score 2):

Вот более быстрый способ сдвига массива методом трёх реверсов.
И как по задаче умеет двигать в обе стороны.

```
using System;

namespace JaggedArrayShift
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int shift = 3;
            int[][] array =
            {
                new[] { 1 }, new[] { 2 }, new[] { 3 },
                new[] { 4 }, new[] { 5 }, new[] { 6 },
                new[] { 7 },
            };
            Display(array);
            Console.WriteLine("------------");

            Rotate(array, shift, true);
            Display(array);
            Console.WriteLine("------------");
        }

        private static void Rotate(int[][] array, int shift, bool forward)
        {
            shift %= array.GetLength(0);
            if (forward)
            {
                shift = array.GetLength(0) - shift;
            }
            Reverse(array, 0, shift - 1);
            Reverse(array, shift, array.GetLength(0) - 1);
            Reverse(array, 0, array.GetLength(0) - 1);
        }

        private static void Reverse(int[][] array, int startIndex, int endIndex)
        {
            while (startIndex < endIndex)
            {
                var temp = array[endIndex];
                array[endIndex] = array[startIndex];
                array[startIndex] = temp;
                ++startIndex;
                --endIndex;
            }
        }

        private static void Display(int[][] array)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < array.GetLength(0); i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(string.Join(",", array[i]));
            }
        }
    }
}
```